# I cant do a select by one of its parameters even if it exists in the database. Encoding issues? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a postgresql database snapshot with the following structure

> ```
> id (integer / autoincrement)
> address (varchar)
> balance (integer)
> datetime (date)
> ```

```
    CREATE TABLE public.snapshots
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    address character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    balance bigint,
    datetime date,
    CONSTRAINT snapshots_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.snapshots
    OWNER to postgres;
```

But it has some weird issues, for example I have this data

Some example of data is:

```
12531   "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"    34567733    "2020-09-01"
12532   "0x8cfb1D4269f0daa003CDEa567aC8f76c0647764a"    34547733    "2020-09-01"
12533   "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"    34512333    "2020-09-01"
12534   "0x94d863173EE77439E4292284fF13fAD54b3BA182"    34511133    "2020-09-01"
12535   "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"    34555733    "2020-09-01"
12536   "0x9287130ba603359E9621ae89c4164613BF239Fa2"    34327733    "2020-09-01"
```

Well the problem is now that I do this select

```
SELECT * FROM snapshots where address = '0x9287130ba603359E9621ae89c4164613BF239Fa2'
```

0 returns

But if i do

```
SELECT id, address, balance, datetime
FROM public.snapshots where datetime = '2020-09-01' and balance = 34327733;
```

It does return the result

What is going on? It works with some addresses, but doesn't with others

Comment: If that hexadecimal value is really a `varchar`, you must be using a weird client. Try with `psql`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe im using pgadmin , and pg-promise. None will show it

Comment: I was saying `psql`.

Comment: Often when it seems weird things are happening you need to *question your basic assumptions*. Are you sure your stored data values do not actually include the double quotes. So ' "0x9287130ba603359E9621ae89c4164613BF239Fa2" ' instead of  '0x9287130ba603359E9621ae89c4164613BF239Fa2'. Also how about other values for the same column, do they exhibit the same results?

Comment: is your encoding SQL ascii at client  SQL_ASCII The SQL_ASCII setting behaves considerably differently from the other settings. When the server character set is SQL_ASCII, the server interprets byte values 0-127 according to the ASCII standard, while byte values 128-255 are taken as uninterpreted characters. No encoding conversion will be done when the setting is SQL_ASCII. Thus, this setting is not so much a declaration that a specific encoding is in use, as a declaration of ignorance about the encoding.

Comment: In most cases, if you are working with any non-ASCII data, it is unwise to use the SQL_ASCII setting because PostgreSQL will be unable to help you by converting or validating non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe  using Psql will not change anything. As Pgadmin is more advance tool than PSQL

Comment: @JinThakur I disagree, but that is off topic. It is just that if `psql` displays a `varchar` like this, I can be certain that it is actually `"0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"` with quotes any everything.

Comment: @JinThakur my encoding is utf8 . and the quotes is simply a copy paste , the select works for some addresses and doesnt for others. Its random and I dont see why is it happening. But since it works for some addresses it doesnt seem to be a quote issue. I will try to migrate to ascii encoding and see what happens

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe single quoote is perfectly fine in Postgres  you can run this  SELECT
 SUBSTRING ('PostgreSQL', 1, 8);

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It is PostgreSQL not other language like c# where single quote is for one char only  and for string it shoudl be double quotes

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe dont use double quotes in Postgres https://lerner.co.il/2013/11/30/quoting-postgresql/   Now, there is a way around this, namely by using double quotes.  Whereas single quotes in PostgreSQL are used to create a text string, double quotes are used to name an identifier without changing its case.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Postgres use single quotes for string and not double quotes

Comment: @JinThakur Thanks for the lecture on SQL basics. I think this question is unanswerable unless OP adds a verbatim quote of a `psql` session showing the problem.

Comment: @JinThakur I understand. I will add a psql example. But anyway afaik it has no double quotes, its a simple string , but when copying thedata from pgadmin to paste it into stackoverflow it copied some double quotes (as happened with the date), but the date works without using double quotes, so those are simply some "visual features"

Comment: @JinThakur using directly psql wont work, same issue as postgresql . IDK some addresses will return their values, and some wont, even tho Im sure that all of them are in the databse since I can see it with a select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related with tolowercase lol, I was doing the select in my script with uppercase

Answer (score -1):

There are different collate and encoding in SQL ( lc_collate default) which are set during
database creation.
Now  you have to find out what  is default value.
what's the default collate? Use SHOW to discover that.

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

Now set

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';
```

or

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'LATIN9';
```

or whatever is you server encoding
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/multibyte.html
Then write query it will match the data.

SELECT * FROM snapshots where address = '0x9287130ba603359E9621ae89c4164613BF239Fa2'

Comment: Are you sure? I see only ASCII characters in the question.

Comment: encoding is at database level. default is utf8 .if you have client encoding as ascii and server as UTF8  it will work for some cases but not all.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe  Iam giving him suggestion to try different encoding.As he says it works with some address but not all